# undefined variable: im new in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.3

i think i have done all right in code but this error is coming from i don't know where
please help me i am **new in **cakephp****.

**errors** it is **showing** is:

Notice (8): Undefined variable: officename [APP\Controller\EnduserController.php, line 84]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: visitdays [APP\Controller\EnduserController.php, line 85]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: from_time [APP\Controller\EnduserController.php, line 86]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: to_time [APP\Controller\EnduserController.php, line 87]

please **HELP!!!!!**
this is **my code**:

my **controller**/EnduserController/doctorscheduleend: **doctorscheduleend action**

```
public function doctorscheduleend()
    {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->loadModel('DoctorSchedule');
        $this->loadModel('Doctor');
        $this->loadModel('Office');

        $doctor_name = $this->Doctor->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Doctor.first_name','Doctor.last_name'),'conditions'=>array('Doctor.id'=>$_POST['DoctorId'])));
        $this->set('doctor_name',$doctor_name);

        foreach($doctor_name as $row)
        {
            $doctor_first_name = $row['Doctor']['first_name'];
            $doctor_last_name = $row['Doctor']['last_name'];
        }

        $schedule = $this->DoctorSchedule->find('all',array('fields'=>array('DoctorSchedule.office_id','DoctorSchedule.visitdays','DoctorSchedule.from_time','DoctorSchedule.to_time'),'conditions'=>array('DoctorSchedule.doctor_id'=>$_POST['DoctorId'])));
        $this->set('schedule',$schedule);


        foreach($schedule as $row)
        {
            $office_id  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['office_id'];
            $visitdays  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['visitdays'];
            $from_time  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['from_time'];
            $to_time    = $row['DoctorSchedule']['to_time'];
        }

        $office = $this->Office->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Office.office_name'),'conditions'=>array('Office.id'=>['$office_id'])));/*editted here $officeid to ['$office_id']*/

        foreach($office as $row)
        {
            $officename = $row['Office']['office_name'];
        }

        $tablerows = "";
        $tablerows.= "<tr>
                        <td colspan='4' style='color:white;'>Schedule Of Dr. ".$doctor_first_name." ".$doctor_last_name."</td></tr></br>
                      <tr>
                        <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>Hospital</th>
                        <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>Visitday</th>
                        <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>From</th>
                        <th width='20%' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#0c884b'>To</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>".$officename."</td>
                        <td>".$visitdays."</td>
                        <td>".$from_time."</td>
                        <td>".$to_time."</td>
                      </tr>";

        echo $tablerows;
    }
```

my **model** DoctorSchedule:

```
<?php 
class DoctorSchedule extends AppModel {
    public $name='DoctorSchedule';
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A State Name is required'
            )
        ),
        'country_id' => array('notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please Select Country'
        ),
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Doctor' => array(
            'className' => 'Doctor',
            "foreignKey" => 'doctor_id'
        ),
            'Office' => array(
            'className' => 'Office',
            "foreignKey" => 'office_id'
        )
    );




}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to be *old* in cake for this... just define the variables that the error says are undefined...

In your controller

```
$office_id  = $visitdays = $from_time  = $to_time = officename  = "";

foreach($schedule as $row)
{
    $office_id  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['office_id'];
    $visitdays  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['visitdays'];
    $from_time  = $row['DoctorSchedule']['from_time'];
    $to_time    = $row['DoctorSchedule']['to_time'];
}

/* and etc the rest of your code */
```

And btw... why in the name of all that's holy do you have a table echoing from a controller? Is there no way to return a JSON array (or xml) and leave the rendering of the table to the url calling the action?